Laravel/Jetstream: dynamically filled dropdown list in registration form
I have watched several videos and read some related tutorials about customization of the register form of Laravel/JetStream registration system. All I found is something like this:
//resources/views/auth/register.blade.php

<div class="mt-4">
    <x-label for="gender" value="{{ __('Gender') }}" />
    <x-dropdown id="gender" class="block mt-1 w-full" name="gender" :value="old('gender')" required>
        <x-slot name="content">
            <option value="0">Select Gender</option>
            <option value="1">Female</option>
            <option value="2">Male</option>
        </x-slot>
    </x-dropdown>
</div>

However I want to populate the genders dropdown from a database table, say "genders".
For this I have created a model Genders.
All I need to do is adding the following line
//this line will be in a file but which one?
$genders = Genders::all();

Then I will be able to list the items in the view, as follows:
<div class="mt-4">
    <x-label for="gender" value="{{ __('Gender') }}" />
    <x-dropdown id="gender" class="block mt-1 w-full" name="gender" :value="old('gender')" required>
        <x-slot name="content">
            <option value="0">Select Gender</option>
            @foreach ($genders as $gender)
                <option value="{{$gender->id}}">{{$gender->name}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </x-slot>
    </x-dropdown>
</div>

I have added the following code into app/Providers/FortifyServiceProvider.php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Actions\Fortify\CreateNewUser;
use App\Actions\Fortify\ResetUserPassword;
use App\Actions\Fortify\UpdateUserPassword;
use App\Actions\Fortify\UpdateUserProfileInformation;
use Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiting\Limit;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Laravel\Fortify\Fortify;
use App\Models\Gender;

class FortifyServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     */
    public function register(): void
    {
        //I have added this but no change ):

        Fortify::registerView(function () {
            $genders = Gender::all();
            return view('auth.register', ['genders' => $genders]);
        });
    }

I could not find where should I put the code $genders = Genders::all(); and pass $genders to view register.blade.php? This could simple for a few options but what if I want to list countries for example?

I never knew it was so easy:
I have added
        //
    Fortify::registerView(function () {
        $genders = Gender::all();
        return view('auth.register', ['genders' => $genders]);
    });

into boot() function in app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

// use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Laravel\Fortify\Fortify;
use App\Models\Gender;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The model to policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array<class-string, class-string>
     */
    protected $policies = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     */
    public function boot(): void
    {
        //
        Fortify::registerView(function () {
            $genders = Gender::all();
            return view('auth.register', ['genders' => $genders]);
        });
    }
}

Now I can see a dynamically populated dropdown list.
